I had a question, I can got the console.log data, but when I refresh the page, I got the error
I had a question, I can got the console.log data, but when I refresh the page, I got the error.
console.log(city.value.terms[0].value),
it's show me data Melbourne.

But when I refresh the page, it's show me error.
Unexpected Application Error! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'terms')

Where has problem??
this is my GoogleAddress code
<FilterGoogleAddressSearch name="city" id='city'
  setCity={(value)=>setCity(value)}
  onChange={handleChange}
/>


You're initialising city to a string, so why should it have a .value property?

@NickParsons Because I got value from GoogleAddressSearch, that's why I will use city.value.terms[0].value. I need to this value.

Yes but it starts off as an empty string which is what is giving you your issue. I suggest you start it off as undefined, and if the value of city is undefined display a loading spinner/screen instead. The value of city is only set later once your address search component sets the value.

per your provided screen shot city is defined as an empty string here
const [city, setCity] = useState("").
So what you trying to do is equivalent to "".value.terms[0].value, meaning you are trying to access properties on a string.   "".value === undefined because there is no such property on a string. Next you're doing this undefined.terms. You're trying to read a property of undefined.    You're gonna need to set the value of city to an object with the structure you expect.

Because I got value from GoogleAddressSearch, that's why I will use city.value.terms[0].value.

when you use const [city, setCity] = useState("") the value you pass in between the () is the initial value of city.   That means, on the first render of the component, city is === "".  You are also trying to console log properties from city on the first render when it is still an empty string.   It's not shown in your code, and you may eventually change the value of city to something else, but at the time you are logging it in the provided code city is === ""
